# Formulas for range not applying correctly

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, office-addins

I'm trying to link two rows using the HYPERLINK Excel function with the following code, where `full_range` is the result of `worksheet.getUsedRange()` and 18 is the amount of columns of my test sheet.:

```
let row11 = full_range.getRow(10)
    let formulas = new Array( 18 ).fill("=HYPERLINK(A100; \"test test test \")")
    row11.formulas = [ formulas ]
```

This doesn't work, however. The add-in crashes (and reloads the embedded browser, which closes the DevTools window, meaning I can't see any error messages), and in row 11, this is what I see:

[image]

Clicking on the cell doesn't take me to row 100, though.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The following formula works when inserted on a cell manually, but not when inserted via the add-in (as a hard-coded string, no variables). The addin crashes and the formula appears as a cell value:

```
=HYPERLINK("[Grouping test file.xlsx]\'WEKA 18 rec2\'!A100"; "test test test")
```

Comment: see: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/hyperlink-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f `A100` is not a correct link, it must be the full external reference.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @ScottCraner , but I'm getting the same result. I'll update my post with a new picture

Comment: use the  full external ref with quotes: `=HYPERLINK("[ddddddd.xlsx]Sheet2!A100","test test test")`

Comment: Thanks again Scott. This solution doesn't work fully though. Clicking the linked cells gives me a "Reference isn't valid" error, and some cells still have only the formula and not the link. The resulting formula looks like this: `=HYPERLINK("[Grouping test file.xlsx]WEKA 18 rec2!A100"; "test test test")`, and in the cells where it wasn't applied: `"=HYPERLINK("[Grouping test file.xlsx]WEKA 18 rec2!A100", "test test test")"` (, instead of ;)

Comment: The idea is that you need to get the formula to work in the sheet before trying to code it.  Then code it to match what works.  If your formula use `;` then use `;`.  My formula use `,`

Comment: I originally put a comma on the formula, Excel replaced it with a semicolon. However, putting a semicolon on the formula crashed the add-in. Also, the original formula from my question works in Excel, but not when inserted via the add-in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212100/discussion-between-tuma-and-scott-craner).

Comment: I am interested in the crash issue, i have tried your sample code, it doesn't repro in my side, would you please share a bit more your code, it would be great if you could share the script lab gist. Our team will do some investigation on this issue

Comment: Hi Raymond. This add-in is pretty complex and unfortunately I can't share much of the code. I'll move this question to github.